# Keeping Bluetooth Connection all Fragment with Class

Tags: android

How can i keep bluetooth connection at all fragment i am using bluetooth class and i can receive message correctly. I am connecting but my server socket close other fragment so i can not send message how can i do for this ?
This is my bluetooth connection https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gcPrydZnDw/

I am calling new connection this way on the fragment :

```
 mBluetoothService = new BluetoothConnectionService(getActivity());
           BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

           device=btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(adress);
           mBluetoothService.startClient(device,MY_UUID_INSECURE);
```

Comment: hi, how did you solve this issue? I got main activity that handles change in fragments using a view pager, with 3 tabs. In the first fragment the BT is discovered, conected, receive and send message. Can´t make it to bind the service in the second and third tabs son they can interact with the BT device already connected in the first tab.